# swift: AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate methods are not called in the login view controller

Tags: swift, aws-userpools

I am trying to login using AWSCognito User pool but the AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate methods are not being called. Here is my code, where am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import AWSCognito
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

class LoginViewController: UIViewController,     AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
var passwordAuthenticationCompletion: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>?
let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
var user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    loginButton.layer.borderWidth = 1

    pool.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func loginTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
        if email.isValidEmail() {
            let authDetails = AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails.init(username: email, password: password)
            self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: authDetails)
            self.user?.getSession()
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Invalid Email or password", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func cancelButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("goToPaymentPageVC"), object: nil)
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}


//:- MARK: AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate methods
func getDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput, passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>) {
    self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion = passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if (self.emailTextField.text == nil) {
            self.emailTextField.text = authenticationInput.lastKnownUsername
        }
    }
}

func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error",
                                                    message: error.userInfo["message"] as? String,
                                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
            let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(retryAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
        } else {
            self.emailTextField.text = nil
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("goToPaymentPageVC"), object: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Expected result: AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate methods should be called and the loginViewController should dismiss.

Comment: I believe you need to call `self.user?.getDetails()` instead of `self.user?.getSession()`

Comment: I have tried both. None of them work.

Comment: Is `user` being set and not `nil`?

Comment: no its not set. where and how should I set it? I had tried `pool.getUser(email).getSession()` . it didn't work as well

Comment: Try `user = pool.currentUser()`. You can set it right before you use it. And I don't think `getSession()` is what you need. Change it to `getDetails()`. Also, I assume you're using your actual key to create the UserPool and not the "UserPool" string shown above.

Comment: Hey, it didn't work either I use my own key or "UserPool". Neither does it work with current user and getDetails(). I don't know what is wrong. Also, setting it to current user returns nil

Comment: Have you implemented the required Cognito setup in the AppDelegate?

Comment: `AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose
let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .EUCentral1, credentialsProvider: nil)
let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "*****",
clientSecret: "*****",poolId: "****")AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration, forKey: "**")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it was fixed:

1. Conform the class `LoginViewController` to `AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication` and added the following function in the same class

   `func startPasswordAuthentication() -> AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {
       return self
   }`
2. Adding `pool.clearAll()`before calling `self.user?.getSession()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
pool.clearAll()
```

before you perform the login procedures

```
let authDetails = AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails.init(username: email, password: password)
        self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: authDetails)
        self.user?.getSession()
```

If you already logged in on that specific device/simulator before, the AWS SDK does not call the respective methods.